# ReactJS Server Side rendering click event won't fire

Tags: reactjs, rendering, server-side

I have this code which is compiled server side with node-jsx but click events do not fire. Being novice I can't figure out what I missed

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var React = require('react/addons')
var mui = require('material-ui');
var ThemeManager = new mui.Styles.ThemeManager();
var injectTapEventPlugin = require("react-tap-event-plugin");

var UnyDentApp = React.createClass({

    childContextTypes: {
    muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object
      },

    getChildContext: function() {
        return {
          muiTheme: ThemeManager.getCurrentTheme()
        };
      },

    componentDidMount: function () {

      },

    render: function () {
        var menuItems = [
          { route: 'home', text: 'Home' },
          { route: 'about', text: 'About' },
        ];

        return (
          <div id="uny-dent">
            <mui.LeftNav
              ref='leftNav'
              menuItems={menuItems}
              docked={false} />
            <mui.AppBar
                title="UnyDent" onMenuIconButtonTouchTap={ this._handleClick }/>
          </div>
        )
      },

    _handleClick: function()
      {
        alert('ok');
      },

    toggleNav: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert();
        this.refs.leftNav.toggle();
      }
  });

/* Module.exports instead of normal dom mounting */
module.exports = UnyDentApp;
```

Comment: Probably binding the handler to an event.

Comment: sorry I missed the event handler but in my snippet, but the status quo is the same

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're attempting to do what is commonly referred to as "Isomorphic React". This differs from simply rendering a react template server-side (resulting in rendered *static* page) in that it also supports "mounting" the react component(s) client-side (resulting in a rendered *dynamic* page).

Right now you're simply doing the former, and therefore React isn't actually running client-side, so the click-event isn't actually "wired up".  There are several different solutions to isomorphic react. Here's one in particular from the Paypal team: https://github.com/paypal/react-engine

Comment: Thank you for feedback I will check it in details